# When using classify() of pavo package, how can I correct the mouse click position in Rstudio's plot window?

Tags: r, plot

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331649615_pavo_2_new_tools_for_the_spectral_and_spatial_analysis_of_colour_in_R

recently I was learning the analysis method in the above paper, installed the pavo package, ran Rstudio with the data and code provided in the article (the data provided in the article: https://github.com/rmaia/pavo, or https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.7445840), proceeded to section 6.2 of the article, when I used classify() function, there is a problem when selecting the image color in the plot window, the code is as follows:

```
> heli_images <- getimg("heliconius_plates")
28 files found; importing images. ＃There are 28 images in the data, so this line appears 28 times
> plot(heli_images)
Press [enter] for next plot #There are 28 images in the data, so this line appears 28 times
> heli_class <- classify(heli_images, interactive = TRUE)
Select the focal colours in image mimic_01, and press [esc] to continue.
Duplicate colours specified. Try again.
Select the focal colours in image mimic_01, and press [esc] to continue.
```

I found that when using the classify() function of the pavo package, the selection position displayed by the plot window is inconsistent with the position I actually clicked with the mouse (as shown in the screenshot, the black cross is the position where I clicked when I operated, and the red circle is the position of the selection displayed by the plot window), so the above error will appear saying that I selected a duplicate color in the blank space of the plot window, let me reselect, but the offset distance of the mouse seems to be not fixed, I also can't estimate where I should click.

[image]

I later tried to use this method directly in R 4.3.1, where the mouse click position was not offset, but the problem was that I could not process multiple images in a row, and when I selected the color of the first image in the plot window and pressed the esc key when prompted, the classify function directly stopped running instead of processing the next image.

How can I correct the mouse click position in the plot window of Rstudio? Or finish running the classify() function in R 4.3.1?